# <terminated> Java program in Eclipse, Unsure Why

Tags: java, eclipse

and welcome to my question.

I am working on homework, and after attempting to create an array at the size of 10000, all that displays is (terminated) BubbleSortApp...

Here is the code that I am working with:

This creates the buble sort

```
// bubbleSort.java
// demonstrates bubble sort
// to run this program: C>java BubbleSortApp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class ArrayBub {
    private long[] a; // ref to array a
    private int nElems; // number of data items

public ArrayBub(int max) // constructor
{
    a = new long[max]; // create the array
    nElems = 0; // no items yet
}

public void insert(long value) // put element into array
{
    a[nElems] = value; // insert it
    nElems++; // increment size
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
public void display() // displays array contents
{
    for (int j = 0; j < nElems; j++) // for each element,
        System.out.print(a[j] + " "); // display it
    System.out.println("");
}

public void bubbleSort() {
    int out, in;
    for (out = nElems - 1; out > 1; out--) // outer loop (backward)
        for (in = 0; in < out; in++) // inner loop (forward)
            if (a[in] > a[in + 1]) // out of order?
                swap(in, in + 1); // swap them
} // end bubbleSort()

private void swap(int one, int two) {
    long temp = a[one];
    a[one] = a[two];
    a[two] = temp;
    }
} // end class ArrayBub
```

Here is the Driver

```
    class BubbleSortApp {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int maxSize = 101; // array size
            ArrayBub arr; // reference to array
        arr = new ArrayBub(maxSize); // create the array
        for (int j = 0; j <= maxSize-1; j++)// fill array with
        { // random numbers
            long n = (long) (java.lang.Math.random() * (maxSize - 1));
            arr.insert(n^2);
        }
        arr.display(); // display items
        arr.bubbleSort(); // bubble sort them
        arr.display(); // display them again
    } // end main()
} // end class BubbleSortApp
```

I've looked around stackoverflow and other places and havent seen an answer that helps.

Why does it not display the numbers at all? I tested different numbers and I noticed that 6624 was the maximum maxSize that I could create to get it to display numbers. Any more and it just says terminated. How do i fix?

Comment: Try to add try catch block in every method and print the stack trace. It will help to resolve the issue

Comment: It's working fine. If you are using Eclipse to run the program, it's console is having some issue to display the output. You need to limit the console's width. Right click on console -> preferences -> select Fixed width Console.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your program. The problem is the way how output is shown on console. Change the

```
System.out.print(a[j] + " "); // display it
```

to

```
System.out.println(a[j] + " "); // display it
```

It is displaying the numbers.

Comment: Why would this be a problem?

Comment: @AndréStannek His eclipse console is not fixed width and he is appending the result to one line and it is not seen on screen (it's off screen on right).